# Как получить ограниченный доступ к аккаунту Telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Можно ли получить доступ к аккаунту телеграма, чтобы только отправлять сообщения определенному боту?

Я знаю, что есть сайт Telegram API и там можно получить доступ к аккаунту пользователя, но так я получу полный доступ к аккаунту, а это может напугать человека, который захочет воспользоваться моей программой, да мне и не нужен полный доступ. Нужна только возможность писать сообщения одному боту. Такое вообще можно сделать?